# While I was waiting for

Tags: tenses, sentence, past-tense

Which one is grammatically correct?
I want to say that I waited the time that the bus would leave the terminal in the past tense.

- While I was waiting for the bus leaves, a man came to talk to me.
- While I was waiting for the bus to leave, a man came to talk to me.
- While I was waiting for the bus left, a man came to talk to me.

Comment: None of these are a complete sentence in American English.

Comment: Nor British English. Also "I waited the time that the bus would leave the terminal" doesn't make sense either. The second option is a grammatical ***phrase*** but it's not a complete sentence and does need something else. You may need to concrete examples with times in order that we can work out the sequence of events you are attempting to describe.

Comment: Only the middle one is possible, assuming it is a dependent clause and will be followed by the main clause. We wait **for** something **to** happen. _We are waiting **for** you **to** tell us the whole sentence_.

Answer (score 5):

Number 2 is best although gramatically incorrect. It should be: While I was waiting for the bus to leave, there was a man **who** came to talk to me.

Comment: Or perhaps better: *While I was waiting...a man came to talk to me*.

Answer (score 1):

True, none of them is a complete sentence. But assuming they are meant as phrases: #2 is correct, #1 and #3 are grammatically incorrect. I don't know of any difference between American and British English in this matter.